# amazon Mws Secret_Key without qualifications for use

Tags: amazon-mws

I have registered to be the developer associated with seller account and filled developer registration and assessment but I got the message '`amazon Mws Secret_Key without qualifications for use`.

What did I miss? and how I could get the access Secret_Key?

Answer (score 0):

As of late Amazon has changed the request process. In the past I was able to request access and have access on the same day. Now there is a new and much longer process. After the registration and assessment Amazon MWS will review your request for up to 60 days (this was the case for me). You can check the status by logging into your Amazon seller account and click on case log. If there is no response to your request then it's still in the review process. Something to keep in mind, when submiting your request it is important that your application followed the acceptable use policy and data protection policy to the T.

Information about Amazon MWS access requirements can be found in the Acceptable Use Policy and Data Protection Policy:
http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/dev_guide/DG_AcceptableUsePolicy.html
http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/dev_guide/DG_DataProtectionPolicy.html

For more information about the Developer Registration and Assessment form, please see the FAQ: http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/faq.html

Hope that helps.